# Peeking in notes from Samsung Smart Switch's backup

Tags: notes, samsung-smart-switch

My Samsung Galaxy S6 just drowned and I'd like to get stuff that I saved in Notes. I did some googling to find out what the app is called. I found some people referring to Memo, but I don't think that is right in my case.

I can't check this out because my phone just died. It is a "Note" app with a yellow icon and it comes with the OS.

The backup to my PC was made with Samsung Smart Switch.
Where are the notes located in the backup, and how can I read it?

Comment: Did it look anything like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJK1f.jpg)
 Or like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prDM9.jpg)?

Comment: Hmmm, the Memo icon looks familiar. Could be Memo....